# How to log in to a Dialog Box using URLConnection?

Tags: java, android, cookies, authentication, urlconnection

Currently I have an app that is supposed to connect to WebAPI(uTorrent).

However, when I try to reach the site, I have to log in.

It looks like this in my browser

https://gyazo.com/cfb535c4ca1d7db2b16f1c14e3b8e9e6

How do I log in into this dialog box ? username:password@url didn't seem to work.

Is there a way to log in using Http Headers? This is my method, with which I am supposed to log in and get a cookie. However this did not log me in.

```
  public String getCookie(String url, String post_data, int len) {
     System.out.println();
     URL addr = null;
     try {
         addr = new URL(url);
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         return "Malformed URL";
     }
     StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
     HttpURLConnection conn = null;
     try {
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) addr.openConnection();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return "Open connection error";
     }
     conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ru,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "");
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     conn.setDoInput(true);
     //conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
     for (int i = 0; conn.getHeaderField(i) != null; i++) {
         if(conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i).equals("Set-Cookie")) {
             cookie = conn.getHeaderField(i);
             System.out.println(conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i));
             System.out.println("COOKIE" + conn.getHeaderField(i));
         }
     }
     System.out.println("COOKIE HEADERS" + conn.getHeaderFields());
     return cookie;
 }
```

This is how I call it:

readWebsite.getCookie("http://192.168.1.5:8080/gui/token.html","uname=login&pw=password",1000);

The whole method looks weird to me and it's definitely not working how I intended, but this is the only thing I found on here.

The problem is that the official WebAPI for uTorrent doesn't mention at all how to fix this.

I'd like to add that I get "401 error"->unathorized from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've long found an answer that works, but I definitely can't guarantee any network security. You need to add an "Authorization" header.

```
    String authorization = "Basic " + new  String(android.util.Base64.encode((auth).getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP));

    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
```